# GUARDAR DATOS DE UN FRAME HIJO A UNA TABLA DEL FRAME PADRE

Tags: c#

Tengo un frame padre al dar el boton nuevo, me abre su frame hijo que tiene cajas de texto y un boton guardar, lo que deseo es que al llenas mis cajas de texto mis datos se muestren en mi datagridview de mi frame padre , ojala me puedan ayudar porfavor.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que es un frame? podras mostrarnos el codigo?

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que tienes una pagina 1.aspx que contiene un iframe que muestra la pagina 2.aspx

en 2.aspx puedes poner

```
           <a href="1.aspx" target="_parent">Actualizar todo</a>
```

de esta forma se recarga la pagina principal (1.aspx)

NOTA: La próxima vez publica tu código, es mucho mas fácil entendernos viendo el código.

Comment: Es mejor no responder este tipo de preguntas. Mira [answer]